# Convert CharSequence To a IntegerArray

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding, integer

I try to convert a CharacterSequence directly into a integer array with the single integers.

```
CharSequence nbr = "478";
int j;
int[] testArray = new int[100];

for(j = 0; j <= nbr.length() - 1; j++)
    testArray[j] = Character.getNumericValue(nbr.charAt(j));

System.out.println(testArray);
```

Instead of the desired [4,7,8] the Console gives back something like that:

```
[I@424c2849
```

Setting up a switch with the cases '0','1',...,'8','9' and corresponding assignment did not solve the problem.

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays don't override the `toString` method. So, when you try to print any array, the `Object` class `toString` method is invoked, and you get the representation returned by that method, which is of the form - `Type@hashCode`

To get the required representation, use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29) method to print array: -

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testArray));
```

Apart from that, you really should declare your integer array as:

```
int[] testArray = new int[nbr.length()];
```

rather than using `100` size.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
    CharSequence nbr = "478";
    int j;
    int[] testArray = new int[100];

    for(j = 0; j <= nbr.length() - 1; j++)
        testArray[j] = Character.getNumericValue(nbr.charAt(j));

    for(int i : testArray){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: This will work (sort of ... you'd get multiple lines each with one number), but you really should be using the `Arrays.toString()` method provided.